# c++ function returning template type checking

Tags: c++, templates, types, return, token

I have read through some questions here and cant find anything specific to my problem so I don't know if I am doing it completely wrong or just am missing something specific.

What I am trying to do is tokenize some data and input that into a function and return data as a specific type depending on what data got read into or return bool false if the validation of input fails. I have over 20 .cpp and 20 .h files so I will only post here the relevant section and hope that is enough...

```
#include "utility1.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


string buffer;

template <class T>
bool loadStaff(char* staffName) {

   ifstream staffFile;
   T data;
   int datapos = 0;

   staffFile.open(staffName, ios::in);

   if (!staffFile.is_open()) {
      cout << "Cant open file: " << staffName << endl;
      return false;
   }

   while (staffFile.good()) {
      getline(staffFile, buffer);
      tokenizer<> tok(buffer);

      for (tokenizer<>::iterator pos=tok.begin(); pos!=tok.end(); ++pos) {
         data = validate(datapos, *pos);
         //  want to type check 'data' here
      }
   }

   staffFile.close();
   return true;
}

template <class T>
T validate(int datapos, string token) {

   switch(datapos) {

   case 0:
      if (sizeof(token) != 2)
         return false;
      else 
         return token;
      break;
   }
}
```

So how should I go about this? would casting work? or would it not since it might change data types instead of checking what data type it is.

For the first check I wanted to check if validate returns a bool false and then cause an error (later will change to a try and catch statement but right now just want to get it working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: why is `validate` a template? what would it return other than false or true?

Comment: sorry it is not finished yet, it will return the data as a int or string or double depending on what the data position is, eg. if anything fails it will return false, but if it is successful it will return either a string, int, double etc depending on the data position.

Comment: I jsut changed it to make a small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler needs to know the type of each expression on compile time and you're trying to make a function whose return type is known only on runtime.

Instead create a base class for all the types you want to return and return a pointer to it (so that virtual methods work).

If you also want to return bool when validation fails you can return for example `std::pair<bool, base_token *>` where the first item signalizes whether the validation was successful and if yes then the second item is valid pointer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, no way to force this to work using the return types in the code on compile time since that wont change? doubt it but still interested if allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm probably using the wrong terms, but basically have the compiler create the functions based instead of what value gets entered but instead on what value gets returned

Comment: well, with the function signature being the same it would create ambiguous function call.

Comment: thanks, in order to do this but using a template I will just turn the token into int / double / string then use a function that takes that as a template and returns a bool that returns true or false for validation. Thanks for sorting this out.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. You're trying to make the template parameter T depend on a run-time variable - while a template parameter must be deduces at compilation.

What you can do instead is use [boost::any](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.any).

Comment: boost any is what I would normally use however my lecturer wants a template example so trying to do something similar with that.

Comment: In order to help you, please specify your lecturer's requirements more clearly.